# vimrc - Syntax highlighting not working

Tags: vim, syntax, colors, terminal

so this is what my .vimrc contains, why is my syntax highlighting not working?

```
set nocompatible " must be the first line
filetype plugin indent on
syntax on
set laststatus=2
set statusline=%<%f\%h%m%r%=%-20.(line=%l\ \ col=%c%V\ \ totlin=%L%)\ \ \%h%m%r%=%-40(bytval=0x%B,%n%Y%)\%P
set nu
set shortmess=I
set nowrap
set tabstop=2
set backspace=indent,eol,start
set shiftwidth=2
set shiftround
set ignorecase
set smarttab
set hlsearch
set incsearch
set undolevels=1000
set pastetoggle=<F2>
set t_Co=256
colorscheme monokai
let g:user_emmet_leader_key = '<c-y>'
execute pathogen#infect()
autocmd StdinReadPre * let s:std_in=1
autocmd VimEnter * if argc() == 0 && !exists("s:std_in") | NERDTree | endif
autocmd vimenter * NERDTree
```

My color theme works, but the colors are not showing up properly as syntax highlighting.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What file type are you editing? (`:set filetype`)

Comment: :set filetype sets the filetype correctly, mostly using PHP.

Comment: There is `vim -V` to trace the startup, but it's not always helpful. Last time I broke my vimrc I had to replace it with `/usr/share/vim/vim74/vimrc_example.vim` and add my customisations to it. It's recommended to use that distribution vimrc as the basis, as it contains a lot of default settings and fixups - it's meant to work out of the box.

Comment: `:set bg` also can influence colors. You can set it to either `light` or `dark`. See also `:help 'bg`. Your terminal type is another thing to check (`echo $TERM` in a shell).

Comment: So this all doesn't seem to work. The problem doesn't seem to be my .vimrc, neither any of zsh-configs, neither the $TERM variable. Has to be something else related to the SuSE box. Don't have control over that :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, check the output of:

```
:setlocal syntax?
```

The correct output (for php files) is:

```
syntax=php
```

You can check the php syntax code doing a:

```
:syntax list
```

You must see all syntax code with the command above. If you don't get the `syntax=php` value or don't see any syntax code on `:syntax list`, probably you don't have a `php.vim` file in your `~/.vim/ftplugin` folder. When you set `filetype plugin on` and open an php file, what Vim does is to look in your `ftplugin` folder for a `php.vim` file and execute it.

`php.vim` is a system file, and it comes with the default installation. Try to do a `:scriptname` to see all scripts that are opening with vim. If you can't see a php.vim file, a solution could be install [StanAngeloff/php.vim](https://github.com/StanAngeloff/php.vim) plugin.

If, and only if, you have a `php.vim` file and see its syntax with `:syntax list`, then something external is affecting Vim's syntax highlight, and it's probably your terminal.

Comment: Thanks, turns out the system didn't have any syntax files anywhere. Fixed it.